# moxy how to find object set null or the object is not given

Tags: null, jaxb, moxy

```
@XmlRootElement
class Person{
String id;
String name;
}

JSON
{
“id”：null
}
```

I want to find the id that is set to null and the name is not given in the json。I know the method the object set to null will  invoke the set method。But I have so many object I want not do as that。If have general method。
I need you help @Blaise Doughan

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage `JAXBElement` for this.  One of the roles of `JAXBElement` is to handle the case where an XML element is both nillable and optional:

```xml
<element name="foo" type="string" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>
```

### Domain Model

**Person**

We will leverage field access (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html) for our `JAXBElement` and code our accessor methods to look the way we want.

```java
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
class Person {

    static final String ID = "id";
    static final String NAME = "name";

    @XmlElementRef(name=ID)
    JAXBElement<String> id;

    @XmlElementRef(name=NAME)
    JAXBElement<String> name;

    public String getId() {
        if(null == id) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return id.getValue();
        }
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = new JAXBElement<String>(new QName(ID), String.class, id);
    }

    public String getName() {
        if(null == name) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return name.getValue();
        }

    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = new JAXBElement<String>(new QName(NAME), String.class, name);
    }

}
```

**ObjectFactory**

When we leverage a `JAXBElement` on a field we need to have a corresponding `@XmlElementDecl` on a class annotated with `@XmlRegistry`.

```java
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {

    @XmlElementDecl(name=Person.ID)
    public JAXBElement<String> createId(String id) {
        return new JAXBElement<String>(new QName(Person.ID), String.class, id);
    }

    @XmlElementDecl(name=Person.NAME)
    public JAXBElement<String> createName(String name) {
        return new JAXBElement<String>(new QName(Person.NAME), String.class, name);
    }

}
```

### Demo Code

Below is some code you can run to show that everything works.

**Demo**

```java
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextProperties;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>(2);
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, "application/json");
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.JSON_INCLUDE_ROOT, false);
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] {ObjectFactory.class, Person.class}, properties);

        Person person = new Person();
        person.setId(null);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(person, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

```java
{
   "id" : null
}
```